# How to use addLiquidityETH from UniswapV2?

Tags: python, web3py, uniswap

I am having a problem using the "addLiquidityETH" function from Uniswap Protocol, it was working before but now is always saying insufficient amount.

So far i made sure to have enough tokens to spend, approved to spending both tokens, the pool and pool LP.
I tried to forced hardcoded amounts that metamask was about to send on their transaction data to the pool but it still fails, but on metamask not.
I checked the transaction data inputs from metamask with the values i send on the code(token amounts and token path) and they look the same, right now don't know what more checks to do.

I was looking if someone knows what usually is the process to use this kind of function's and all the checks i should make before using it, or if is there something wrong with the code i made to use the "addLiquidityETH", any help would be appreciated.

Note: I always make sure the weth is involved when using the "addLiquidityETH"

UniswapRouter Class

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from decimal import Decimal
from math import trunc
from web3 import Web3
from service.uniswap.constants.uniswap_token_router_abi import UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER_02_ABI

# https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02
# Uniswap Router ABI
# https://unpkg.com/@uniswap/v2-periphery@1.1.0-beta.0/build/IUniswapV2Router02.json

class UniswapRouter(object):
"""
Service class for using Uniswap Router.
"""

ROUTER_ABI_02 = UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER_02_ABI

def __init__(self, rpc_address:str, block_explorer:str, web3_options:dict) -> None:
    self.rpc_address = rpc_address
    self.block_explorer = block_explorer
    self.web3_options = web3_options

def getAmountsIn(self, contract_address:str, token_amount_out:Decimal, tokens_path:list, slippage:Decimal=Decimal(1.0)):
    """
    Used to retrive the minimum input of tokens.
    
    :param contract_address: 
        Uniswap router contract address.
    :param token_amount: 
        Amount of tokens
    :param tokens_path: 
        Route from tokens e.g: Token_A->Token_B or Token_A->Token_B->Token_C it can also be reversed.
    
    :returns :
    
    """
    
    try:
        # Setup account web3
        w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(self.rpc_address))
        contract_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(contract_address)
        contract = w3.eth.contract(contract_address, abi=UniswapRouter.ROUTER_ABI_02)
        
        amount_wei = Web3.toWei(token_amount_out,'ether')
        path_to = list()
        for address in tokens_path:
            path_to.append(Web3.toChecksumAddress(address))
        
        if len(path_to) < 2:
            raise Exception('Error: "tokens_path" should have at least 2 addresses!')
        
        result = contract.functions.getAmountsIn(amount_wei, path_to).call()
        
        amount_out = dict()
        amount_out["amountWei"] = result[1]
        amount_out["minInpWei"] = result[0]
        amount_out["amount"] = Web3.fromWei(result[1], 'ether')
        amount_out["minInp"] = Web3.fromWei(result[0], 'ether')
        
        # Slippage
        ca_slippage = (1-(slippage/100))
        ca_amount_out_slipppage = amount_out["minInp"] * ca_slippage
        ca_amount_out_decimals = trunc(Web3.toWei(ca_amount_out_slipppage, 'ether'))
        amount_out["minInpSlippageWei"] = ca_amount_out_decimals
        amount_out["minInpSlippage"] = Web3.fromWei(ca_amount_out_decimals, 'ether')
        
        return amount_out
    
    except BaseException as error:
        raise Exception(f"Error:{error}")


def add_liquidity_eth(self, account_pk:str, router_contract_address:str, token_address:str, token_amount:Decimal,
                    token_amount_min:Decimal, amount_weth_min:Decimal):
    """
    Should only be used with on ERC20/WETH pairs or when WETH is involved.
    """
    
    try:
        # Setup account web3
        w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(self.rpc_address))
        account =  w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(account_pk)
        w3.eth.default_account = account.address
        account_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(account.address)
        token_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(token_address)
        nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(Web3.toChecksumAddress(account_address),"latest")
        transaction_args = {'gasPrice': w3.toWei(self.web3_options["gas_price"], 'gwei'), 'nonce': nonce}
        
        # Setup contract with web3
        contract_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(router_contract_address)
        contract = w3.eth.contract(contract_address, abi=UniswapRouter.ROUTER_ABI_02)
        
        if token_amount_min <= 0 or token_amount <= 0 or amount_weth_min <= 0:
            raise Exception(f"All token and weth amounts should be greater than 0!")
        
        if token_amount_min >= token_amount:
            raise Exception(f"token_amount:{token_amount} should be greater than token_amount_min:{token_amount_min}!")
        
        token_amount = Web3.toWei(token_amount,'ether')

        token_amount_min = Web3.toWei(token_amount_min,'ether')
        amount_weth_min = Web3.toWei(amount_weth_min,'ether')
                   
        # Deadline for transaction
        deadline = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=0,seconds=self.web3_options["transaction_deadline"])
        timestamp_deadline = trunc(deadline.timestamp()*100)
        tx = contract.functions.addLiquidityETH(token_address, token_amount, token_amount_min, amount_weth_min,
                                                account_address, timestamp_deadline).buildTransaction(transaction_args)
        
        # Sign transaction
        signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=account_pk)
        encoded_sent_transaction = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
        
        print(f"Waiting for transaction: {signed_tx.hash.hex()} to be mined....")
        tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(transaction_hash=signed_tx.hash, timeout=self.web3_options["transaction_timeout"],
                                                        poll_latency=self.web3_options["poll_latency"])
        print(f"Transaction mined! Block explorer: {self.block_explorer}{signed_tx.hash.hex()}")
        
        # Check if transaction was made with success
        tx_receipt_status = tx_receipt["status"]
        if tx_receipt_status == 0:
            raise Exception(f"Transaction failed, receipt status:{tx_receipt_status}! Block explorer:{self.block_explorer}{signed_tx.hash.hex()}")
            
    except BaseException as error:
        raise Exception(f"Error: {error}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. It was working and now saying "web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_AMOUNT". I have tried everthing I know to fix this but

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32454503)